# Get variable from table cell

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I am displaying a list of contracts and services in a table, these both have an ID.

When you click on the cell of the contract or service it should got to a details page.  I have the ContractId/ServiceID saved in the `id` attribute, like so:

```
<td class="TableCell" id="@ID">
    Sometext
</td>
```

and I retrieve it here:

```
var id = this.id;    
// the following is an MVC thing, don't worry about it
var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "services", new { id = "__id__" })'; 
window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);
```

This all works great, but now I want to save another variable in the table cell like so:

```
<td class="TableCell" id="@ID" value="@Variable2">
    SomeText
</td>
```

I know this won't work, but what is the best way to do this?  Is using the `id` attribute for passing variables a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly:

> Is using the `id` attribute for passing variables a good idea?

If the ID you're passing can be thought of as the ID of that element, there's certainly no problem with it.  If it's not really *the ID of that element*, but the ID of something else, then *conceptually* it's not a good idea.

In a more general sense, the usual approach to storing additional data in HTML attributes is to use `data-` attributes:

```
<td class="TableCell" data-id="@ID" data-var2="@Variable2">
```

If you're on [a modern browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Browser_compatibility), you can then use the `dataset` property to access them:

```
var id = this.dataset.id;
var val2 = this.dataset.var2;
```

Otherwise, you can use the [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method with the full attribute name:

```
var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
var val2 = this.getAttribute('data-var2');
```